# What is the best way to exit and handle a fatal error in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say my app does something unrecoverable (this never happens, right? :P ). Should I use exit()? Should I use NSAssert(false, @"Foo")? Should I throw something somehow? Hard answer to google for.

Comment: The standard solution is to launch Pong or Rogue in another window on the opposite side of the screen to distract them while you quietly restart your application. At least, I sure wish Xcode would do this instead of presenting a, "Hey, would your like me to crash now? Howzabout now?" dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should force quit your app if something bad happens as it is annoying for the user - they won't have a clue about what went wrong. Also, Apple are likely to reject your app if this is a common enough occurrence.

Instead you should pop up a dialog to say what went wrong (eg error writing to database, please try again).

If your app can end up in a state where it is totally broken, you should re-design your app. Could you give an example of something "unrecoverable"?

Comment: Perhaps this is the wrong question to ask, which is why I'm not finding an answer. First this isn't an ios app. And I am popping up a dialog. The issue I'm currently working on is an unknown file system error. But I'm currently worried that the state of the application won't be functional after this occurs, so I would like to exit out. I guess I could create a 'quit fast' method that just exits out of the application normally? Since this would not occur (hopefully) with a release version of the project, I wanted to put the app out of its misery i guess.

Comment: If it's not an iOS app then I think the user experience of having an "This application encountered an error and must quit" is more acceptable. Even so, you should only use this as a last resort - try and handle the error gracefully.

Comment: Reflecting on this I think I wasn't really asking a good question. Thanks for your help. That is pretty much what I'm doing right now, but the hope is that the user will never see this code.

Comment: Explicitly crashing an app is a valid choice. See "fail fast". Just trying to keep the app running at any cost even when your data has become corrupted is silly. There ought to be a way to gracefully exit your app.

Answer (score 0):

If your app does something really unrecoverable, chances are that it will be terminated by the O.S. without you having the possibility of knowing it. Think of accessing a deallocated object.

If your are considering errors or unforeseen conditions that your program might detect, then it depends very much on what it is about. But a general policy is:

1. informing the user about the fact that an error happened;
2. trying to recover as much as possible;
3. gracefully exit the application.

1 and 3 explicitly rule out both `NSAssert` and `exit()` options you mention. Throwing does not help either, because if you throw an exception and don't handle it, your program will be terminated abruptly.

Gracefully exiting means exiting like in a normal case, when all dealloc methods are called, all files are closed, all resources are released. And possibly store enough information about the running state of the program so that it becomes possible to recover at the next startup.